# MySQL timestamp auto-update performance

Tags: mysql, performance

We are considering adding an auto-updated timestamp field to mysql tables to track the last time rows are updated, as described in the mysql documentation here:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html

The question I can't seem to find an answer to is what is the general performance impact with this? I can't imagine it being slower than a trigger (unless it simply creates a trigger internally) but suspect it would be slower than updating the field during your update statement.

Comment: What does your testing reveal? My guess is basically nothing. Committing the transaction is going to be vastly more expensive than twiddling a four byte value.

Answer (score 6):

So, benchmarked a bit on a thin, one million row table:

[image]

So it appears at least on a thin table, adding a timestamp column and using ON UPDATE is a bit slower. However using ON UPDATE is actually faster than manually updating the timestamp field. Trigger performance was terrible.

Comment: And the reason "I refuse" on the AFTER UPDATE trigger is because you can't modify the row you just updated. Which means you actually have to update twice. No, thank you.

Comment: Any clue of why "on update" times had such a high Variance?

Comment: Not sure, change on server load perhaps. I did other similar tests though and numbers were about the same, with ON UPDATE still being the fastest and manual update just behind.

Comment: OK.  I guess the slight speed diff is because `ON UPDATE` is "built into the server", but 'manually' involves some extra parsing.

Comment: I appreciate the benchmark showing how much slower a Trigger is.

Comment: @AS7K , what's the time unit for the values in the benchmark table? I know it's been a long time since you answered the post :-). Do you remember?

Comment: @AhmadFerdous I don't think I limited, just waited. But hey that was like 3 years ago! Also, sorry I didn't get to this comment until now!